# Java JSP search results filtering / prioritization

Tags: java, html, jsp, search

Please bear with me as I'm no programmer, but  I have a company intranet search site that searches a specific database for objects and returns a table of results.  The metadata labels I'm concerned with are essentially "Type", "Name", and "Revision".   In this database,  we might have the same document captured with a "Type A", a "Type B", and a "Type C" where the Name and Rev are the same for all three.

Currently, when you submit your "Name" search through the htm site,  the JSP is configured to return all types, but only the newest/latest revision.    I want to modify the coding  (preferably in the htm if possible)  to also give priority to the types as well as if they were in a sequential order like the revisions  (rev 1, 2, 3, etc).

For example:  if the search finds two items of the same name and rev,   I only want the Type A to be displayed and ignore the Type B and C.
If Type A, does not exist, or does not have a valid file link,  the search results should only display Type B.
And again if A and B do not exist, display Type C.

Any ideas if this can be achieved in the htm functions or variables?    Or does this have to be coded in the JSP that the htm refers to?

```
<HTML><HEAD>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
function setHiddenValues()
{
    var index = document.thedatabase_search.Document_Type.options.length;

    var type="";
    for(var i=0;i<index;i++)
    {
        if(document.thedatabase_search.Document_Type.options[i].selected)
        {
            if (type=="")
            {
                type = eval("document.thedatabase_search.Document_Type.options["+i+"].text");
            }
            else
            {
                type = type + "," + eval(""document.thedatabase_search.Document_Type.options["+i+"].text");
            }
        }
    }
    document.thedatabase_search.type.value=type;


    var revisionOptions = document.getElementsByName("radio1");
    var selectedRev = "";

    for(var j = 0; j < revisionOptions.length; j++)
    {
       if(revisionOptions[j].checked)
       {
           selectedRev = revisionOptions[j].value;
       }
}

if (selectedRev=="Specified")
{
        document.thedatabase_search.revision.value=document.thedatabase_search.Document_Revision.value;
}
else
{
        document.thedatabase_search.revision.value=selectedRev;
}

    var docName = document.thedatabase_search.Document_Name.value;

    if (docName=="" || docName == "*")
    {
        alert("Please specify Name");
        return false;
    }

    if (document.thedatabase_search.Document_Name.length < 2)
    {
        alert("Atleast two characters should be specified in Name field");
        return false;
    }

    if (document.thedatabase_search.Document_Revision.value=="")
    {
            alert("Please specify revision");
            return false;
    }


    //document.thedatabase_search.Document_Name.value = document.thedatabase_search.Document_Name.value + "*";
    //document.thedatabase_search.Document_Title.value = document.thedatabase_search.Document_Title.value + "*";



    var trimmedName = docName.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    if (trimmedName.length<2||trimmedName.substring(0,1)=="*"||trimmedName.substring(1,2)=="*")
    {
        alert("Atleast two characters should be specified in Name field\nThe first two characters of Name field cannot be '*'");
        return false;
    }

    if (trimmedName.slice(-1)!="*")
    {
        document.thedatabase_search.Document_Name.value=trimmedName.concat("*");
    }

    var docTitle = document.thedatabase_search.Document_Title.value;
    var trimmedTitle = docTitle.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    if (trimmedTitle == "")
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (trimmedTitle.length == 1 && trimmedTitle == "*")
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (trimmedTitle.length == 1 && trimmedTitle != "*")
    {
        alert("Atleast two characters should be specified in Title field\nThe first two characters of Title field cannot be '*'");
        return false;
    }
    else if (trimmedTitle.length >= 2)
    {
        if (trimmedTitle.substring(0,1)=="*"||trimmedTitle.substring(1,2)=="*")
        {
            alert("Atleast two characters should be specified in Title field\nThe first two characters of Title field cannot be '*'");
            return false;
        }
    }

    if (trimmedTitle.slice(-1)!="*")
    {
        document.thedatabase_search.Document_Title.value=trimmedTitle.concat("*");
    }


    document.thedatabase_search.name.value=document.thedatabase_search.Document_Name.value;
    document.thedatabase_search.short_description.value=document.thedatabase_search.Document_Title.value;
    document.thedatabase_search.current.value=document.thedatabase_search.Document_State.value;


    document.thedatabase_search.action="/documentSearch/DocumentSearchResults.jsp";
    document.thedatabase_search.method = "post";
    document.thedatabase_search.submit();"

}

function enableRevisionField()
{
document.thedatabase_search.Document_Revision.disabled=false;
document.thedatabase_search.Document_Revision.value="";
}

function disableRevisionField()
{
document.thedatabase_search.Document_Revision.disabled=true;
document.thedatabase_search.Document_Revision.value='disabled';
}

function disableRevisionAndStateField()
{

document.thedatabase_search.Document_Revision.disabled=true;
document.thedatabase_search.Document_Revision.value='disabled';

document.thedatabase_search.Document_State.disabled=true;
document.thedatabase_search.Document_State.value='disabled';

}

function clearFormValues()
{
document.thedatabase_search.Document_Name.value="";
document.thedatabase_search.Document_Title.value="";
document.thedatabase_search.name.value="";
document.thedatabase_search.short_description.value="";
}

</SCRIPT>




<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.7601.18305"></HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="document.thedatabase_search.Document_Name.focus()"><BR><BR>
<HR>
<B>
<CENTER><FONT face=arial size=5>This is the Search Header</FONT></CENTER></B>
<HR>

<FORM onsubmit="return setHiddenValues()" name=thedatabase_search><!-- Value used in jsp page - STARTS -->

<!-- type should be of form TypeA,TypeB,TypeC -->
<!-- company should not edit this line -->
<INPUT type=hidden name=type>

<!-- revision can be one of the following
revision = A or B or any valid value in objects revision chain
revision = All
revision = Latest
revision = Latest_Released
revision = Highest_By_State -->

<!-- company should not edit revision here -->
<INPUT type=hidden name=revision>

<!-- name can have wildcard characters Example: Test* -->
<!-- company should not edit revision here -->
<INPUT type=hidden name=name>

<!-- current can have any State value from the list Example: Preliminary -->
<!-- company should not edit revision here -->
<INPUT type=hidden name=current>

<!-- short_description can have wildcard characters Example: Test* -->
<!-- company should not edit revision here -->
<INPUT type=hidden name=short_description>

<!-- user should be a single value; This a mandatory -->
<!-- company should edit this line and provide proper account to be used Based on this account name the key file will be generated for the division by corporate-->
<INPUT value=DocSearchUser type=hidden name=user>

<!-- results_field - the columns to be present in resulst page;The results table will show values in the order specified here
Acceptable values - Type, Name, Revision, State, Short_Description, FileLink, Owner, Originator,Originated, Modified, Release_Date

companies may edit this line to add or remove fields from the Acceptable values -->
<INPUT value=Type,Name,Revision,Short_Description,State,FileLink type=hidden name=results_field>
<!-- Value used in jsp page - ENDS -->

<!-- company may edit this to specify their own title to appear in the search results page here -->
<INPUT value="Search Results" type=hidden name=title>


<TABLE border=1 width=500 align=center>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD height=40 width=200><B>Document Name<B></B></B></TD>
<TD><INPUT name=Document_Name></TD></TR>

<TR>
<TD height=60><B>Document Type</B></TD>
<TD><SELECT id=Document_Type multiple size=3 name=Document_Type>
<OPTION selected value="TypeA">TypeA</OPTION>
<OPTION selected value="TypeB">TypeB</OPTION>
<OPTION selected value="TypeC">TypeC</OPTION>
<OPTION value=*>All</OPTION></SELECT> </TD></TR>

<TR>
<TD height=50><B>Document Revision<B></B></B></TD>
<TD><INPUT disabled value=disabled name=Document_Revision>
<TABLE border=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT id=Latest onclick=disableRevisionField()
value=Latest CHECKED type=radio name=radio1> <LABEL for=Latest>Latest</LABEL></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT id=Latest_Released onclick=disableRevisionAndStateField()
value=Latest_Released type=radio name=radio1> <LABEL for=Latest_Released>Latest Released</LABEL></TD>
</TR>
</TBODY>
</TABLE>
</TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD height=40><B>Document Title</B></TD>
<TD><INPUT name=Document_Title></TD>
</TR>

<TR>
<TD height=40><B>State</B></TD>
<TD><SELECT id=Document_State name=Document_State>
<OPTION selected value=*>*</OPTION>
<OPTION value=Preliminary>Preliminary</OPTION>
<OPTION value=Review>Review</OPTION>
<OPTION value=Approved>Approved</OPTION>
<OPTION value=Release>Release</OPTION>
<OPTION value=Obsolete>Obsolete</OPTION></SELECT> </TD></TR>
</TBODY></TABLE><BR><BR>

<CENTER><INPUT value=Submit type=submit> </CENTER></FORM></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the database where you pull the documents from? More specifically, what type of access do you have?

Comment: John,  through the thin-client, I have a power-user access, but that log in and access is independent from this search site.  The search site can be used by anyone on the intranet.  It's simply a URL that loads in IE and allows them to search through the htm intranet page.

Comment: Still working on this. Unsure if this filtering can be done in my html file or if it has to be in the JSP?